# Почему не работает код? Дело в названии функции?

Tags: python, переменные, модули

Не понимаю, в чем ошибка. Дело в названии модуля? Возникает ошибка int is not callable

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVYn1.jpg

Comment: Код надо вставлять текстом.

Comment: наверное потому, что функция и переменная одного имени?а вообще можно прочитать текст ошибки и подумать, почему же "целочисленный тип не вызываем", ошибки не просто так появляются

Answer (score 3):

Как выполняется ваш код:
 - Питон читает определение функции `а` и создает объект функции,  связанной с именем `а`
 - затем питон читает `а=2`,  и связывает имя `а` с целым числом со значением 2. Функция `а` становится недоступной.
 - затем программа пытается вызвать функцию `а`. Питон смотрит на имя `а`, и видит, что это целое число (int). И тогда он выдает сообщение об ошибке

```
   int is not callable
```

что можно перевести как «Целое число невозможно вызвать (как вызывают функцию)».

Этот код хорошо приводить как пример на лекции про пространство имен.
**Уточнение:** Как пример-загадку «Что напечатает этот код?»

Comment: Этот код хорошо приводить как пример на лекции про то, как не стоит писать код :D

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в том, что у вас функция и переменная имеют одинаковые имена.